# how to derive forward differencing formula using taylor series?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximation

How can I derive the forward differencing formula using Taylor series in order to approximate  derivative of a function at some point $x$?

I don't see how we can link the two formulas. I came across a solution where:

$$ f(x) = f(a) + f^{\prime}(a)(x-a) + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(a)(x-a)^{2}}{2!} $$

$f(a)$ was replaced by $f(x_{i})$ and $f(x)$ was replaced by $f(x_{i+1})$ but I don't see why?

Next, $f^{\prime}(x_{i})$ was taken out and it was equal to
  $$f^{\prime}(x_{i}) = \frac{f(x_{i+1})}{h} + \frac{f(x_{i})}{h} + \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h}{2}$$

where

$$ h = x_{i+1} -x{i} $$ and the last term is the error term.

Does this suffice as an answer?

Comment: Hi there! I've replaced your formatting with latex without changing any of the mathematics. I can't help but think some of the mathematics is wrong. Maybe you could take a look now that it is formatted and edit your question to make sure the maths is accurate?

Comment: I missed what h represents. Does my qs sound clearer now? @Shai

Comment: That definitely seems better. Are you sure about the Taylor expansion though? It seems like it has an extra term (unless there's a reason I'm not aware of for the term in $(x-a)^{2}$ to appear twice, I think you probably want only $\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(a)(x-a)^{2}}{2!}$ and not the other one).

Comment: Oops yess @Shai

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not sufficient. You need to combine
\begin{align}
f(x_i)&=f(x_i)\\
f(x_{i+1})&=f(x_i)+f'(x_i)h+\frac12f''(x_i)h^2+\frac16f'''(x_i)h^3+...\\
f(x_{i+2})&=f(x_i)+2f'(x_i)h+2f''(x_i)h^2+\frac43f'''(x_i)h^3+...\\
\end{align}
to eliminate $f(x_i)$ and the second derivative terms on the right side.

Comment: I don't really understand what rule/formula you're applying here. Could you explain a bit? Why was $$f(x)$$ replaced by$$ f(x_{i+1})$$ in the first place?